# jQuery datepicker is defaulting to Norwegian even though my browsers language is en-US?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

If I set my browser to `en-GB`, the `datepicker` works fine, but if I set it to `en-US`, the `datepicker` is formatting in `Norwegian`, so it appears it is using the language file for `Norway`.

I am testing in IE and my languages are in this order:

`en-US`

`en-GB`

`fr-FR`

I don't even have Norway listed.

My scripts are in this order:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Fingerprint.Tag("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")%>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Fingerprint.Tag("~/Scripts/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-en-GB.js")%>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Fingerprint.Tag("~/Scripts/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js")%>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Fingerprint.Tag("~/Scripts/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-no.js")%>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to the party, but the script file

```
~/Scripts/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-**no**.js
```

is the settings for Norwegian language.

If you could add some code of how you use the datepicker I guess it would be easier to see what is going wrong. en-US is the default format for the datepicker so you should not need any configuration-file to get the language correct.